# Generate google map release api key

Tags: google-maps

I am able to generate debug key for google map V2 using "keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "/home/niket/.android/debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android" this in commandPrompt. Now I have to publish my app on google play which key should I use and How to generate it ...I have creates signed keystore also for my app.... Please provide step-by-step procedure for genrating release key for google map V2.